# Centos 7 Oracle Database 12c Installation Out of Memory

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

I am new to Oracle Database Installation and I tried to install newer version but it does not work, and when I get a full documentation on how to install version 12c, somehow I got an error out of memory.

When I check in this path: ***/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl***

```
[ 2023-04-19 16:37:55.751 GMT ] Copying database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 1%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 2%
[ 2023-04-19 16:38:01.236 GMT ] ORA-27102: out of memory

DBCA_PROGRESS : 3%
[ 2023-04-19 16:38:01.238 GMT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2023-04-19 16:38:02.301 GMT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2023-04-19 16:38:02.305 GMT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2023-04-19 16:38:07.537 GMT ] DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed.
```

When I check in this path: ***/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace***

```
2023-04-19T16:38:01.221832+00:00
Dump of system resources acquired for SHARED GLOBAL AREA (SGA) 

2023-04-19T16:38:01.221951+00:00
 Per process system memlock (soft) limit = 128G
2023-04-19T16:38:01.222002+00:00
 Expected per process system memlock (soft) limit to lock
 SHARED GLOBAL AREA (SGA) into memory: 820M
2023-04-19T16:38:01.222103+00:00
 Available system pagesizes:
  4K 
2023-04-19T16:38:01.222200+00:00
 Supported system pagesize(s):
2023-04-19T16:38:01.222254+00:00
  PAGESIZE  AVAILABLE_PAGES  EXPECTED_PAGES  ALLOCATED_PAGES  ERROR(s)
2023-04-19T16:38:01.222306+00:00
        4K       Configured          209924            2149   ORA-27102
2023-04-19T16:38:01.222355+00:00
```

My current config during installation is this:

```
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 1987162112
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default = 262144
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 262144
net.core.wmem_max = 1048586
```

My current memory: ***[root@testing etc]# free -m***

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2048         855         269         496         922         696
Swap:           512         191         320
```

After close the installer and check back my RAM

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2048          76        1120         496         850        1474
Swap:           512          24         487
```

Can you help me to identify the correct config for my database?

Comment: It's expecting 820M of RAM to be available, and you don't have that much. It's throwing the error after only finding 8M available. Per the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/server-hardware-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation.html), you need at least 1GB available RAM and 2GB is preferred. Looks like your host is rather resource challenged. If this is a VM, you need to increase the memory allocation by at least a couple more GB.

Comment: @pmdba may I know if there is less spec for oracle database?

Comment: @pmdba after i close the installer, i have more RAM now, is it possible to install in silent mode? i think the GUI took the RAM

Comment: The specs given in the doc are the minimum required (1GB min, 2GB preferred). A silent install requires the creation of an response file, which is created using the GUI. See here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oui-silent-installations

Answer (score 0):

How much memory/SGA are you are trying to allocate during installation? Try reducing the SGA size.. maybe it would work